# Explaining Valence Electrons

Tags: electrons, conductors, insulators

I want to explain the concept of free electrons in a conductor vs. an insulator as simple as possible for children that have not yet learned about valence electrons.

Would it make sense if I explained as:

As this [website](http://www.electricalterminology.com/conductor-vs-insulator/) puts it, the atoms in a conductor are structured in such way that they act like a group of people that are willing to pass their ball randomly around. If a battery is connected it makes the atom line up and pass the electrons in a single stream, which would result in an electric current. And an insulator would be a group of people that are not willing to share their electrons and hog them so that no electricity is conducted.

If it doesn't would there be a way that I can be more accurate with the analogy?

Comment: What age are the children? As a general comment, younger are the students and better service to their formation is to provide them experience, experiments, and facts more than theories or models. It is easier, funnier, and less prone to introduce misconceptions that could be hard to remove later.

Comment: Why not just teach them what valence electrons are, in the most basic way (without going into technicalities you deem unnecessary)? Something tells me that, if they can understand this analogy (which involves atoms and electrons), then they can understand the concept that for some kinds of atoms/materials, some of the electrons are loosely bound (or "attached" or "held" or whatever equivalent word makes sense to them).

Comment: You are right, I will explain valence electrons as they are. Thanks for the ideas folks!